# Pythonic way of using a variable as part of another variable?

Tags: python, date

That's the clearest I could make my title.

I have some code that reads in two CSV files. One CSV file has the data, and the other has information about this data... let's call it config.

```
data_jan2018.csv
data_feb2018.csv
config.csv
```

Now, config has columns for which dates I want to read in. I'm reading these in as follows:

```
data_config = pd.read_csv(loc + data_config_name)

# Read in dates from config file
dates = data_config.drop_duplicates('Start_date')
dates = dates[['Start_date','End_date']]
print(dates)
Start_date = dates['Start_date'].tolist()
End_date = dates['End_date'].tolist()

StartDate = ''.join(Start_date)
EndDate = ''.join(End_date)

print(StartDate)
print(EndDate)

date1 = datetime.strptime(StartDate, '%d%b%Y')
date2 = datetime.strptime(EndDate, '%d%b%Y')

# Loop across months
for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY, dtstart=date1, until=date2):
    print(dt)

    reporting_date = dt.strftime('%d%b%Y')
    reporting_date_fmt = dt.strftime(date_format)

    print('Formatted reporting_date is ' + reporting_date_fmt)
    source_data = pd.read_csv(loc + source_data_name)
    source_data.columns = source_data.columns.str.lower()
```

As you can see, I want to read in a csv file called `source_data_name`. However, this file name contains my formatted `reporting_date_fmt`. I want the programmer to edit the file name at the beginning of the code so I have these line right at the top:

```
date_format = '%b%Y'
source_data_name = 'g4_RWA_sample_' + reporting_date_fmt + '.csv'
```

But of course this flags a warning, telling me reporting_date_fmt hasn't been created yet. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: You want the person using your code to edit your code to fill in a variable? Wouldn't it be better for your program to accept a command line argument?

Comment: Can't you just declare `source_data_name` before `source_data = pd.read_csv(loc + source_data_name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define data name separately at the top of the file, then append the format and extension after the format has been defined.

```
data_name = 'g4_RWA_sample_'
...
source_data_name = data_name + reporting_date_fmt + '.csv'
```